# How to use requests for web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

This is my first time trying to web scrape and I am following a tutorial. So far the code that I have is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/rankings/national-universities')

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alanwen/Desktop/webscrape.py", line 4, in <module>
    source = requests.get('https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/rankings/national-universities')
  File "/Users/alanwen/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alanwen/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alanwen/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/alanwen/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alanwen/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.usnews.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=None)
[Finished in 25.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/alanwen/Desktop/webscrape.py"]
[dir: /Users/alanwen/Desktop]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands]
```

Comment: might be a good idea to find another url as that one is a bit 'huge'. retail/furniture store should be a good sample. 

example: https://www.bigsave.co.nz/product/aloe-wall-plaque/

just get the price, image, name for a start

Comment: Oh no, if you are just learning and aren’t restricted to python 2 switch over to python 3! There are plenty of python 3 guides for web scrapping

Answer (score 0):

You have to add .text at the end of your requests line to get the actual source code of the webpage. Instead of

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/rankings/national-universities')

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Do

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/rankings/national-universities').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())
```

If you get the error `bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?` install the `lxml` module via pip

Answer (score 0):

this website for the first time web scraping is a bad choice, because this website not a normal website for scraping i think , you must use it [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os
import time


chromedriver = "driver/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

url = 'https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/rankings/national-universities'

driver.get(url)
source = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score -1):

This page needs `User-Agent` header to recognize browser. It can be even incomplete `Mozilla/5.0` but `requests` normally sends `python-requests/2.23.0`.

Without correct header this server blocks connection and after some time you may get message with `"timedout"` because `requests` couldn't wait longer for data from server.

**BTW:** `BeautifulSoup` needs `source.text` or `source.content` not `source` (which is `requests` object).

---

Working code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/rankings/national-universities'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())
```

---

**BTW:** Using page https://httpbin.org/ you can check what you send to server

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
#r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post')
#r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
#r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/user-agent')

print( r.text )
#print( r.content )
#print( r.json() )
```

you can also check (if you use url with `/get` or `/post`)

```
print( r.json()['headers']['User-Agent'] )
```

or you can check in requests object

```
print( r.request.headers['User-Agent'] )
```

and you will see `User-Agent`

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.23.0", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5f07c942-067f5b72784a207b31e76ce4"
  }, 
  "origin": "83.23.22.221", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}

python-requests/2.23.0

python-requests/2.23.0
```